# Filtered Back Projection : Cannot reconstruct image using backprojection Algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv, signal-processing, medical-imaging, tomography-reconstruction

I am learning FBP and for the last 1 month, I am stuck on Backprojection Algorithm. I have done the following steps till now.

- Create Sinogram (Radon Transform)
- Create  Filter (hanning Filter: i used the hanning window function to implement the filter)
  I know Ram filter works the best but I want to research how a different high pass filter will work on this.
- Fast Fourier Transform.(using `dft` function)
- Apply the filter
- Inverse Fourier Transform(using `dft` function)
- Pass the filtered sinogram through the backprojection algorithm.
  I am sharing 2 functions here:
- Traditional Backprojection Algorithm (Found From [LOC: 29](https://github.com/verobuckina/CTSimulator/blob/d30d6ea0e1343c5d6a969381ff93a61a98ad4fa5/CTSimulator/BackProjection.cpp))

```
Mat backprojectionTraditional(Mat inversefft) {
    
    Mat reconstruction(inversefft.size(), CV_32F);
    
    int numOfAngles = 180;
    int dtheta = 180 / numOfAngles;
    for (int x = 0; x < reconstruction.size().height; x++) {
        double delta_t = M_PI / 180;
        for (int y = 0; y < reconstruction.size().width; y++) {
            reconstruction.at<float>(x, y) = 0.0;
            for (int theta = 0; theta < inversefft.size().width; theta += dtheta) {
                int s = (x - 0.5 * inversefft.size().height) * sin(theta * delta_t) +
                    (y - 0.5 * inversefft.size().height) * cos(theta * delta_t) + 0.5 * inversefft.size().height;
                if (s > 0 && s < inversefft.size().height) {
                    reconstruction.at<float>(x, y) += inversefft.at<float>(s, theta);
                }
            }
            if (reconstruction.at<float>(x, y) < 0)reconstruction.at<float>(x, y) = 0;
        }
    }
    rotate(reconstruction, reconstruction, ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
    return reconstruction;
}
```

- The Iterative way as found in one book [Page-72](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-16-0590-1)

```
Mat backprojectionIterative(Mat inversefft) 
{
    Mat iradon(inversefft.size(), CV_32F);
    Mat projection(inversefft.size(), CV_32F);
    float colsum;
    for (int z = 0; z < 180; z++) {
        projection = imrotate(inversefft, z);
        //imshow("Projected image", projection);
        //waitKey(0);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < inversefft.size().width; i++) {
            colsum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < inversefft.size().height; j++) {
                colsum += projection.at<float>(j, i);
                //cout << colsum << endl;

            }
            for (int k = 0; k < inversefft.size().height; k++) {
                //cout << "Break" << endl;
                //cout << colsum << endl;
                //cout << iradon.at<float>(k, i) << endl;
                iradon.at<float>(k, i) += colsum;
                //cout << iradon.at<float>(k, i) << endl;
            }
        }
        
        //iradon = imrotate(iradon, 90);
        //normalize(iradon, iradon, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32F);
        //imshow("Reconstructed image", iradon);
        //waitKey(0);
    }
    return iradon;
}
```

Can anyone tell  me how to implement the backprojection algorithm and where is my error?

[Here is the test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTKDE.png)

#P.S - This is my first question, I will fix it as soon as possible if I am not following the community standards.
Thank you.

Edit - Since most of the viewers are not understanding the problem statement, I am uploading the results of both of these functions.
[After Applying the `backprojectionTraditional` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meXjq.png)
[After Applying the `backprojectionIterative` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XitjT.png)

The output should be same or nearly close as the input after applying backprojection.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. I don't see a description of what's actually wrong.

Comment: " and where is my error?" -- which is ? please explain

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope that clears up

Comment: Hard to know. Have you tried using a publictly available tool for this, so you can compare your intermediate variables?